# Missing framework in ios develop of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, frameworks

I have removed the framework from Xcode workspace and modified *every* place that importing that framework, and together with the building Parse of the project setting.

As there is no error showed in Xcode, I thought it's fine to compile, but during link time, there is error shows that the removed framework still needed.

Note that I have already cleaned the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` folder with `rm -rf *`

So how to check why this specific framework still needed to be linked? where to config that?

This shows that we are good with Xcode editor no error showed.

[image]

And this shows I have already removed the formwork cause the problem from the link parse 
[image]

And here is the error when linking the project

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The thing turns out to be I also have to remove the framework from

```
project -> build phases -> Embed Framworks
```